# Allow drag & drop inside control and not outside of it

Tags: c#, wpf, drag-and-drop

I have the following issue with 2 identical controls ( treeview's ) but with different data. If I drag from one to the other it crashes. What I want to do is to prevent the drag from one control to another but still allow drag inside the control itself.

I have tried setting the Allow Drop to false, but this means that I will not be able to drag & drop inside the control.

Do you guys have any ideas?

Comment: When you start dragging from one of the controls, you could take note of which control you are dragging from, and when you handle your Drop (and CanDrop) events, verify that the drag is from the same control.

Comment: Just use a *bool* variable, call it privateDrag.  Set it to *true* before you call DoDragDrop() and check it in your DragEnter event handler.  You have a rockhard guarantee that it was your own control that created the drag object, nobody else can set that variable to *true*.

Answer (score 0):

The drop target events are your friend here: -

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742859(v=vs.100).aspx

The DragOver event is what you want, this is a bubbling event so you could put a handler on some ancestor of both TreeView controls and look at the sender value to determine which TreeView the drag is currently over and if it is over the incorrect TreeView simply set the Effect property in the DragEventsArg to None (this means the drop target doesn't accept the data): -

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.drageventargs.effects(v=vs.100).aspx

See below; you will need to add the logic to decide whether Effect should be set to None or one of the other enumeration values but should get the idea.

```
private void Treeview_DragOver(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
{
   e.Effect = DragDropEffects.None;
}
```